# Unable to set description in the PowerShell incident description text box

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to create an incident using PowerShell, but I am not able to enter data in the incident description text box, which is disabled.

```
[String]$Description ="test"

#  body of request
$body = @{
    contact_type = "$contact_type"
    caller_id = "$caller_id"
    state = "$state"
    impact = "$impact"
    category = "$category"
    urgency = "$urgency"
    cmdb = "$cmdb"
    assignment_group = "$assignment_group"
    short_description = "$short_description"
    Description = "$Description"
}
$bodyjson = $body | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: powershell does not have a box to gray out. [*grin*] so ... what are you talking about?

Comment: how to remove read-only attribute in textarea using powershell

Comment: what are you talking about? there is no "textarea" in powershell. are you talking about WinForms?  or perhaps WPF forms? or a browser window? ... **_what are you talking about ... details, please_**.

Comment: i have create an incident in service snow. But i am not able to set description on that. While checking "read-only " function is used on the service snow description text-area box.  So now i need to know how to set the description.  please guide me.

Comment: PLEASE add that info to your Question. **_that appears to be your real Question._** also, please add your app to the tags ... at the moment you have this Question tagged as being ONLY about powershell ... and the Question is actually about how to interact with your app.